# Grammar derivation

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Given these grammar productions:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to A1B\\
&A\to 0A\mid\lambda\\
&B\to 0B\mid 1B\mid\lambda
\end{align*}$$

And given string $w = 01101$

If I wanted to make a) leftmost derivation and b) rightmost derivation, I thought it would work like this:

a)  $S \rightarrow A1B \rightarrow  01B \rightarrow 011B \rightarrow 0110B \rightarrow 01101$

b)  $S \rightarrow A1B \rightarrow A11B \rightarrow A110B \rightarrow A1101 \rightarrow 01101$

I'm learning about left/right derivations and not sure if they properly applied here.  Maybe someone can tell me where I'm misunderstanding this concept.

EDIT:

Thanks for the great answer, if I'm understanding correctly then I should be doing it like this:

a)  $S \rightarrow A1B \to 0A1B \rightarrow  01B \rightarrow 011B \rightarrow 0110B \to 01101B \rightarrow 01101$

b)  $S \rightarrow A1B \rightarrow A11B \rightarrow A110B \to A1101B \rightarrow A1101 \to 0A1101 \rightarrow 01101$

Comment: from:http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cit596/notes/dave/cfg8.html it seems right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (a) the step $A1B\Rightarrow 01B$ is impossible, because there is no production $A\to 0$. Two steps are required: $A1B\Rightarrow 0A1B\Rightarrow 01B$. The step $0110B\Rightarrow 01101$ is also impossible; again you need two steps, $0110B\Rightarrow 01101B\Rightarrow 01101$.

In (b) you have the same problem with $A110B\Rightarrow A1101$ and $A1101\Rightarrow 01101$: the first should be $A110B\Rightarrow A1101B\Rightarrow A1101$, and the second $A1101\Rightarrow 0A1101\Rightarrow 01101$.

Comment: Thanks again, added an EDIT to make sure I understood where exactly you were talking about.  Also, good thing you pointed out the MathJax correction, I was making right arrows the hard way. +1 and accepted.

Comment: @stackuser: You’re welcome. Yes, the derivations that you’ve added are correct. Just remember that in these derivations you should be using just one production per step.

Comment: I'm kind of struggling with the GNF [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549125/greibach-normal-form-conversion), not sure if you've worked with that before or if you have a second.  I think it's close, but plenty of room for error in what I did.

Comment: @stackuser: That’s Greibach normal form? I’ve not looked at it in years. How were you taught to do the conversion? By converting to Chomsky normal form first?

Comment: Yes I think you convert to that 1st but you have to make sure that it's form is like $V \to a x$ where a is a terminal and x is any number of variables.  I'm not sure but I think the main difference is that in CNF you can't have any more than 2 total on the right side.

Comment: @stackuser: I’m going off-line for a while now, but I’ll try to remember to take a look when I get back.